# How to find "down" interfaces?

Tags: python, cisco

I'm trying to build a Python script where it first shows the description of interface, then checks if the interface has ( up  up ) or (up  down ) no action need else if the interface is ( down down) then print the interface name.

Here's the output before applying the script

```
Switch# show int description | section ABC
Hu1/0/14                       up             up       ABC
Hu1/0/30                       up             down     ABC
Hu1/0/31                       down           down     ABC
```

The output after apply the script should be

```
Hu1/0/31
```

Comment: NTC templates can format show commands for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to talk to a network device like telnet, ssh, netconf etc and module available for each of those methods.

- telnet - [telnetlib](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/18_ssh_telnet/telnetlib.html)
- ssh - [paramiko](https://networklessons.com/python/python-ssh), [netmiko](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko/blob/develop/EXAMPLES.md)

Sample code which should do what you need

```py
import re
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

username = "test"
password = "test"
enablePwd = "test"

verification_cmd = 'show int description | section ABC'

net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type="cisco_ios",ip=host,username=userName,password=passWord,secret=enablePwd)
net_connect.enable()
sh_command_output = net_connect.send_command(verification_cmd)


for line in sh_command_output.split('\n'):
    if re.findall(r'down.*down', line):
        print(line.split(' ')[0])
```